# Employing a change of variables to convert between metrics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

> The spatial metric for a homogeneous, isotropic, three-dimensional space $(r, \theta, \phi)$ is $ds^2 = dr^2 + S_k(r)^2d\Omega^2$  where $d\Omega^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\,d\phi^2$.

($S_k(r) = R\sin(r/R)$ when $k=+1$ (positive curvature), $=r$ when $k=0$ (flat space), $=R\sinh(r/R)$ when $k=-1$ (negative curvature).)

> Employing a change in variables, derive the equivalent metric as a function of $(x, \theta, \phi)$, where $x = S_k(r)$.

I think I oversimplified this problem by simply changing the $S_k(r)^2$ to $x^2$. Does “employing a change in variables” mean something more specific? I’m also not sure how to express $dr^2$ in terms of $x$ since there are three possibilities for $S_k(r)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that currently, your metric reads:

$$ds^2=dr^2+x^2d\Omega^2,$$

i.e. is **not** a function of $(x,\theta,\phi)$. The only "subtlety" is in expressing $dr^2$ as a function of $x$...

---

For example:

$$S_0(r)=r\rightarrow dr =dx\left(\dfrac{dS_0}{dr}\right)^{-1}=dx$$

but for $S_\pm(r)$, differentiating with respect to $r$, you'll get some $r$'s left-over. How can you rewrite these in terms of $x^2=S_\pm^2$ ?..